# Orchard CMS: Empty value in BodyPart

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm developing custom News module for Orchard CMS. My `NewsItem` consists of few parts: `TitlePart`, `CommonPart`, `BodyPart` and my custom `NewsPart`.

When I try to create and save item, `BodyPart` becomes empty (other parts save correctly), and there is `NULL` value in DB.  If I change `Text` column value in `Common_BodyPartRecord` table and then open item in editing mode, editor is empty, no value is loaded.

here is a definition of my `NewsItem` from `migrations.cs`:

```
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("NewsItem", t => t
                .WithPart("NewsPart")
                .WithPart("CommonPart", p => p.WithSetting("DateEditorSettings.ShowDateEditor", "true"))
                .WithPart("TitlePart")
                .WithPart("BodyPart")
                .Draftable()                    
            );
```

I've tried to debug `BodyPartDriver`class.  When I load news item editor in admin UI, `Editor()` method has input `BodyPart part` parameter. this is the instance of `BodyPart` attached to my `NewsItem`. And here `part.Text` is empty string. But `part.base.Record.Text =  "Test"` as  I set in DB table directly.

I can't understand what is wrong here. Other parts like `TitlePart` or my `NewsPart` are working fine. I do not have custom code with this `BodyPart` in my module. Seems I missed something, but what exactly?

In addition. There is an exception in Orchard Error log:

```
2014-10-22 17:25:15,307 [19] Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator - 
Default - HttpRequestValidationException thrown from IContentPartDriver by 
Orchard.Core.Common.Drivers.BodyPartDriver
http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/Admin/News/Edit/56
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous
Request.Form value was detected from the client (Body.Text="<p>123123123</p>").
```

**PS: I've added `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to my `NewsAdminController` class as in default `Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.AdminController`. And now `BodyPart` saves correctly. But seems to me it is not the right way.**

Answer (score 0):

Never modify the database tables or the records directly. Go through the part's properties instead.

What's happening here is that this property is saved both in the record, and in the infoset. When you modify the record and not the infoset, next time you read the property, the infoset value wins and your record value gets overwritten. This is one of many reasons why you should never touch the records yourself.

Comment: you are right about editing fields in DB, thanks, i didn't think about this. but this should be a comment, not the answer.

Comment: Not true: you were asking why what you did was not working, and I answered that. I also told you how to do it properly. That's a 100% valid answer.

Comment: sorry, but you wrote only about why I shouldn't edit DB manually. Nothing about why my `BodyPart` is not saving. After I disabled `ValidateInput` in controller it started to work, but I'm not sure it is a good way here.
So, I've asked about saving `BodyPart` problems, you answered about editing DB. it is not the answer.

Comment: Again, that's not true: I gave a plausible explanation, which is that "when you modify the record and not the infoset, next time you read the property, the infoset value wins and your record value gets overwritten".

Comment: ok. Initial question was, that I created `NewsItem`, added `BodyPart` and when I edit this value in AdminUI nothing has being saved. thats all. only 2 first paragraphs including `NewsItem` definition source code. Forget about editing DB directly, it wasn't the question.

Comment: Not that it's a big deal, but with the initial version of your question, it was hard to say exactly what was wrong, and my answer was a perfectly reasonable and plausible explanation. It came with not only an explanation, but also a workaround. Turned out it wasn't what was happening in your case, so it's fine to not mark it as *the* answer, but an answer it certainly is. I take great care to put comment in comments, and answers in answers.